# Problem with Android Animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-button

In my application I have 6 buttons. In `onCreate()`, I have a `startAnimation()` which will perform animation for the appearance of the buttons. After the call to this method I have `setOnclickListener()`s for each button.

My code in the `onCreate()` looks like this:

```
    startAnimations();

    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    b4.setOnClickListener(this);
    b5.setOnClickListener(this);
    b6.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**The Problem** is: when I tested my application and while the animation starts, I can click any button even if the button didn't show yet. I mean, I can click in the button place and the action related to that button will start.

**I want to force the buttons to NOT respond to the clicks until the whole animation is over.**

Can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you disable your buttons onCreate or by defaut and then when animations ends, enable it.

```
 findViewById(R.id.button1).setEnable(false);
 findViewById(R.id.button1).setEnable(false);
 ....   
 final RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.group_band);
 Animation a = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -100, 0);
 a.setDuration(200);
 a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    findViewById(R.id.button1).setEnable(true);
                    findViewById(R.id.button2).setEnable(true);
                                             ....
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }

                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

            });

 l.startAnimation(l);
```

What do you think?

Comment: Works Great! I set the listener to the last animation in the `startAnimation()` method and it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can done with before call animation button set enabled false

```
b1.setEnabled(false);
```

then call `startAnimations();` then complete on animation you can do with `b1.setEnabled(true);`

like that ...

Answer (score 0):

button.setClickable(false) or button.setOnClickListner(null) maybe?

Maybe set those, and register an AnimationListener. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html). Once onAnimationEnd is called, button.setClickable(true) and/or button.setOnClickListener(this).

Comment: Thats what I'm saying, register an AnimationListener to alert you when the animation is done. When its done allow the buttons to be clicked again.